# Writing Unicode file to Text widget in Python

Tags: python, unicode, tkinter

I am trying to open a Unicode file in Text widget using Tkinter, Here is my code

```
import codecs
def callback():
    matric_name = entry.get()
    with open(matric_name.rstrip('\n')+".txt", 'r') as content_file:
        content = content_file.read()   

    #myFile=file(matric_name.rstrip('\n')+".txt") # get a file handle
    # myText= myFile.read() # read the file to variable   
    # f = codecs.open(matric_name.rstrip('\n')+".txt", mode="r", encoding="iso-8859-1")
    # myText= f.read()
    # print myText
    #  myFile.close()

    print content
    mytext.insert(0.0,content)
```

It is printing correctly, but it's not writing correctly to Text widget

Output on widget is `ÿþS`

Comment: your indentation is messed up, making it hard to understand

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry for bad indentation, Now I have corrected

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the file using the correct encoding. This can be done using the *codecs* module. Once you have read the data in correctly the Tk text widget will accept unicode strings.  As an example here is one that will load a unicode file into a text widget. Give the unicode text file name as a command line parameter.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,codecs
from Tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid()
        self.text = Text(self)
        self.text.grid()

    def Load(self,filename):
        with codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-16') as f:
            for line in f:
                self.text.insert('end', line)

def main(argv = None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    app = App()
    if len(argv) > 1:
        app.after_idle(lambda: app.Load(argv[1]))
    app.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```